# Using fancybox in an AJAX loaded page

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, fancybox

I searched in this group and googled around, but still no luck in answers
I see also that some have my problem, but the threads didn't help, so here I am

The question is easy, and to help you I've packed a .zip with the
files you can test

http://www.ivanhalen.com/fancyproblem.zip

1. I have a main page with some linkes (index.php)
2. Clicking on them loads a snippet througn AJAX (page.php)
3. In the snippet there is one or more links, clicking on them should
   open an iframed fancybox (fb.php)

Well, the fancybox just won't work, except for the first opened link
Then I keep getting a "t is not defined" error in Firefox, that points
me nowhere
I tried really everything I could imagine, but still no luck...

Please, can you help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put the script to `fancybox()` your links in content of the ajax response. Instead, what you want to do is move the `fancybox()` call into the `complete()` callback of the load function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#links a').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(url, function(data, stat, req){
            $("a#popup").fancybox();
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Ok, ok, I moved the fancybox.js file from the AJAX called page (page.php) to the main script (index.php): it's working now!! Thanks!!!

Comment: interesting note: moving the function outside of the call but still in the click function above wont work either - it must be on the success function of the call.